# Android WebView: CSS scale doesn't hide original

Tags: android, css, webview, scaletransform

I'm currently facing the following issue:

I added a WebView to my main activity (api level 22) and loaded some web-content.
At some point you have to select one or more employees from a list, selected employees are being selected with a little transform: scale( , ) animation.
However the WebView does not hide the original element while and after the animation.

IMAGE: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCpcG.png

As you can see, the original element, or sometimes just a fraction of it remains.

here the css I use:

```
.employee {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    padding: 70px 12px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.employee.selected {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
    background-color: #E6EE9C;
    -o-transform: scale(0.95, 0.95);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.95, 0.95);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.95, 0.95);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.95, 0.95);
    transform: scale(0.95, 0.95);
}
```

This phenomenon also applies to the Google Chrome (V:46.0.x) and the standard android browser. Unselecting one item instantly removes all other remnants.
Is there a way to deal with that perhaps with a jQuery animation instead of CSS3? A way to update my device (Acer Iconia One 10 (nt.lc8ee.001)) so that it works without render issues?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I used a different CSS to workaround that issue.
I added a wrapper class + element:

```
.employee-wrapper {
    height: 180px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}
```

and modified the other classes like this:

```
.employee {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 40px;
    line-height: 180px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.employee.selected {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
    background-color: #E6EE9C;
    width: 95%;
    margin: 6px 2.5%;
    line-height: 168px;
    font-size: 38px;
}
```

now it looks the same, with the different, that it doesn't produces any render issues on my device.